# Company car policy

Tags: contracts

I have been using a company car and now I issued a request to return the car and get car cash allowance instead. But HR said that I won't be able to return the car before the end of the lease period, and they sent policy documents which I have never seen before. This was not shared when I requested for the car, neither in starter package nor in the company handbook.

Could someone advise what can be done? I'm going on maternity leave and would like to get the car cash allowance instead of the car.

Comment: Why do would you need a car allowance if you are going on leave? I assume you won't be driving for business reasons while you are out?

Comment: During the leave company will be paying the car benefits anyway. I can either use the car, or cash the car allowance. Since I don't need a car anymore, getting the money would be the best option for me.

Comment: We can't tell you how to interpret or "fight" your company's policies because we don't know what those policies are. Talk to HR, your manager, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Rose.  It looks like you may have run afoul of a few of our guidelines, which can be a bit off-putting for our newer users.    If you have a few minutes, reading the [Help Page](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) may help to alleviate some of the difficulty.

Answer (score 7):

The fact that you are not going to be using the car during this period doesn't reduce their costs, and in fact if you had taken the allowance it really should be stopped when you aren't using it.

You're being greedy. That's a good way to lose this perk entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Come on it is not a reasonable expectation that you can just flop from car to cash.  Cannot return it until the lease is up is very reasonable to me.

I would assert the onus was on you to ask about car policy at the time you requested the car.

I would say use of a car during maternity leave is nice perk.  I think you are getting greedy wanting cash as that is better for you during maternity leave.

Would it be your intention to go back to a car once maternity leave is over?

I worked for company were you got a small flat allowance and nice per mile.  Or a nice flat allowance and and small per mile.  We had to pick one and stay with it.  Seemed pretty fair to me.